# PythonテキストリストTypeError: 'bool'に関して

Tags: python, python3

やりたいこと：
Pythonでテキストを読み込み、
リストから特定文字が含まれていたらその文字を抽出したいです。
ただリストをスライスする際に**TypeError: 'bool'**エラーが発生します。

**エラー内容**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\test\Documents\test\textread.py", line 35, in <module>
    s=New_list[20:35]
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

もし、このエラーの回避方法分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願い致します。
また別の方法で抽出できるのであれば、教えていただけると幸いです。

テキストファイル

```
フォロワー11
コメント5件

Enterキーで投稿します
2022年2月27日  ·

おはよう！

＃元気

2022年2月28日  ·

本日良い天気

＃晴

コメント2件

Enterキーで投稿します

2022年3月1日  ·

テスト 投稿

TEST
#python
#code
#programin
プログラミング
簡単
コーディング
Python簡単
pythonできること

Enterキーで投稿します
2022年3月2日  ·

こんにちわ！

Enterキーで投稿します

2022年3月3日  ·

おはようございます！

Enterキーで投稿します
```

毎回テキストデータが変化しますので、
下記の文字が含んでいたら抽出したいです。

```
#特定文字がNew_listに含まれているかを調べる
New_list = "#python" in New_list and "Python簡単" in New_list and "#programin" in New_list
```

**実現したいテキスト出力**

```
2022年3月1日
テスト 投稿
TEST
#python
#code
#programin
プログラミング
簡単
コーディング
Python簡単
pythonできること
Enterキーで投稿します
```

下記のcodeで試してみましたが、
「#特定文字がNew_listに含まれているかを調べる」ところにand条件を入れたあとには
**TypeError: 'bool'**エラーが発生します。

手前にリストスライス情報を入れるとエラーが発生しません。

```
#スライスして投稿情報取得
s=New_list[20:35]
```

全体コード

```
import locale

#ファイルパステキスト
path = r"C:\Users\test\Desktop\test.txt"

#ファイル読み込む
with open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    mylist = f.readlines()
    print(mylist)

#新しいリスト作成して特定の文字を置換
New_list = []
for x in mylist:
    New_list.append(x.replace("\n", "",).replace(' ', '').replace('·', '').replace('\ufeff', ''))

print(str(New_list))

#リスト長さの結果
# l=len(New_list)
# print(l)
# 39結果

#特定文字がNew_listに含まれているかを調べる
# str_match = [s for s in New_list if "Enterキーで投稿します" in s]
# print(str_match)

# #スライスして投稿情報取得
#    s=New_list[20:35]
#    print(s)

#特定文字がNew_listに含まれているかを調べる
New_list = "#python" in New_list and "Python簡単" in New_list and "#programin" in New_list
print(New_list) 

if True == New_list :
   print("上記の#pythonなどの投稿情報取得")
   
   #スライスして投稿情報取得
   s=New_list[20:35]
   print(s)
   
else:
   print("何もしない")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記の代入文でNew_listがlist型からbool型に書き変わってしまっています。
これは右辺が条件式(評価結果がTrueまたはFalse)となっているからです。

> ```python
> #特定文字がNew_listに含まれているかを調べる
> New_list = "#python" in New_list and "Python簡単" in New_list and "#programin" in New_list
> ```

解決策としてはNew_listとは別に`is_include`を用意すれば良いです。

```python
is_include = "#python" in New_list and "Python簡単" in New_list and "#programin" in New_list

if is_include:
   print("上記の#pythonなどの投稿情報取得")
   
   #スライスして投稿情報取得
   s=New_list[20:35]
   print(s)
   
else:
   print("何もしない")
```

Comment: 早速回答ありがとうございます。できました！勉強になります。因みにですが、毎回テキスト変換するので、
`[20:35]`でスライスすると`#python`など用語が含んでいるテキスト上手く抽出できないです。テキスト毎回変化しても抽出方法ありますでしょうか。

Comment: 投稿年月日をキーワードにして正規表現で投稿ごとのリストを作って、その上で投稿ごとに用語を含んでいるテキストを抽出するのが良いと思います。pythonでは`re`モジュールが正規表現に関する操作で使えます。[正規表現の操作](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html)や
[reモジュールの使い方](https://note.nkmk.me/python-re-match-search-findall-etc/)を参照してみましょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記の方法で試してみます。